# Hide other code in the app.js in the login page of a vue app

Tags: security, vue.js, pageload

I'm creating an app using laravel + vue. Vue loads all the javascript codes in the app.js even in the login page in which the user is not yet authenticated. I don't want to expose all the js codes just yet until user is logged in. Is there any way that I can only show the necessary codes for the login page and not expose all the js code of the app? I'm doing this to also limit the size of app.js being downloaded for the login page to improve page loading time too.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Laravel mix, you can add a new entry point for your login script.

```
mix.js('resources/assets/app/js/app.js', 'public/app/js')
  .js('resources/assets/app/js/login.js, 'public/app/js);
```

So, you can add a @yield statement in your base layout to place scripts declared in the page view.

`base.blade.php`

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @section('sidebar')
            This is the master sidebar.
        @show

        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
        @yield('scripts')
    </body>
</html>
```

`login.blade.php`

```html
@extends('layouts.base')

@section('title', 'Page Title')

@section('content')
    <p>This is my body content.</p>
@stop

@section('scripts')
    <script src="{{ mix('app/js/login.js') }}"></script>
@stop
```

**Edited**

For a SPA you can have another bundled entry point to just define the Login component:

```
Vue.component('login-form', {
  ... component code here
})
```

You can use [vue-plugin-load-script](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-plugin-load-script) to load the `login.js` script in the `beforeEach` method from Vue router. So the component will be available before render the login page.

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  if (to === 'login'){
    await Vue.loadScript('login entry point url here')
  }
  next();
});
```

Also, you can do it inside the page using the `beforeMount` hook. Here an example using a fake promise and entry point.

https://jsfiddle.net/7oj2sxun/3/

If you're using Vue CLI, it already supports lazy loading with dynamic imports.

Here a detailed article:

https://blog.logrocket.com/lazy-loading-in-vue-js/

Comment: this is a vue SPA btw. the problem is that my login page is inside a vue route of the vue app and the login page is a component of the vue app.

Comment: What are you using to bundle your SPA? Laravel mix? Did you create it with vue cli?

Comment: @japhfortin I updated the answer. I hope this could be helpful.

Comment: I am using laravel mix which I believe compiles all assets into a single file - app.js? the file has all my codes even if I'm in the login page.